# 'set' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Tags: python, attributes, set

```
from random import randint
import os
path = os.path.abspath('')

dosya = open((path + "\\asaldb.txt"), "r")
asalsayilar = dosya.readlines()
mindeger = int(input("Minumum Değer Kaç ? "))
maxdeger = int(input("Maximum Değer Kaç ? "))
min=0
max=0
minasallar = []
maxasallar = []
ortakasal = []
ortakasal2 = []

def maxasal():
    global max
    if maxdeger>=int(asalsayilar[max]):
        maxasallar.append((asalsayilar[max]).rstrip('\n'))
        max=max+1
        maxasal()


def minasal():
    global min
    if int(asalsayilar[min])>=mindeger:
        try:
            (asalsayilar[max]).rstrip('\n')
            minasallar.append((asalsayilar[min]).rstrip('\n'))
            min=min+1
            minasal()
        except:
            print("Maximum Asallar :")"""
            maxasal()
    else:
        min=min+1
        minasal()

minasal()

def common_member(a, b):
    a_set = set(a)
    b_set = set(b)
    if (a_set & b_set):
        ortakasal.append((a_set & b_set))
    else:
        print("No common elements") 

common_member(minasallar, maxasallar)
ortakasal.sort()
print((ortakasal[0]).rstrip('{ }'))
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asal.py", line 54, in <module>
    print((ortakasal[0]).rstrip('{ }'))
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

If I do `print (asalortak)`, it becomes like this: `[{'83', '97', '53', '79', '89', '67', '61', '73', '59' }]`

If I do `print (asalortak [0])`, it looks like this:
`{'83', '97', '53', '79', '89', '67', '61', '73', '59', '71'}`, but I need to separate my numbers.

Comment: `asalortak` is a `set` so it's iterable. Just do a loop on it to get the elements.

Comment: Im not understand . Please example give an example.

Answer (score 0):

> I do print (asalortak [0]), it looks like this: {'83', '97', '53', '79', '89', '67', '61', '73', '59', '71'}

that's because `asalortak [0]` is a python `set` which is confirmed by this error.

```
print((ortakasal[0]).rstrip('{ }'))
```

AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

The elements are already "separated". Just iterate on the elements to print them:

```
for e in ortakasal[0]:
   print(e)
```

in a `set`, the order isn't stable/fixed. Used `sorted` to generate a sorted list out of it (sorted alpha, not numerical since numbers are strings)

convert to list:

```
lst = list(ortakasal[0])
```

convert to *sorted* list:

```
lst = sorted(ortakasal[0])
```

you can use `random.sample(ortakasal[0],2)` to select 2 elements at random.

Comment: I will take 2 random data from the asalortak list. so I need to separate the numbers. how can I do ?